# Java Application-IntelliJ tries to connect to ElasticSearch Databases even if I don't have that in dependency or application properties, or code

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, elasticsearch, intellij-idea

Seems that my Intelij is not Intelij enough, so I have an application that connects just to MySQL database, in the pom I have just the dependency for MySQL, in the application properties I have added just the props for MySQL, but when I run the application every time it tries to connect to an ElasticSearch database. That's what I'm getting in the console, I repeat I have no ElasticSearch plugins, no ElasticSearch dependency, and no ElasticSearch properties in the application properties, I have searched a lot one solution for this but I don't find anything, can someone tell me what should I do? I have also reinstalled IntelliJ, same problems.

```
    2022-09-01 14:24:29 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport - Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface it.ProjectMiC.readformatopacchetto.repository.DepositatoreRepository. If you want this repository to be a Elasticsearch repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.
    2022-09-01 14:24:29 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport - Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface it.ProjectMiC.readformatopacchetto.repository.FormatoValidazionePacchettoRepository. If you want this repository to be a Elasticsearch repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.
    2022-09-01 14:24:29 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport - Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface it.ProjectMiC.readformatopacchetto.repository.TipoFormatoRepository. If you want this repository to be a Elasticsearch repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.
    2022-09-01 14:24:29 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport - Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface it.ProjectMiC.readformatopacchetto.repository.ValidazioneRepository. If you want this repository to be a Elasticsearch repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.
    2022-09-01 14:24:29 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 62 ms. Found 0 Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
    2022-09-01 14:24:29 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
    2022-09-01 15:40:33 ERROR o.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer - error while sniffing nodes
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:918)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:299)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.ElasticsearchNodesSniffer.sniff(ElasticsearchNodesSniffer.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer.sniff(Sniffer.java:209)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer$Task.run(Sniffer.java:140)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

That's my pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.Project-MiC</groupId>
    <artifactId>readformatopacchetto</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>readformatopacchetto</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Project for readformatopacchetto Application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <projectlombok.version>1.18.22</projectlombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>9</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try to delete your build directory and rebuild the project from scratch. Does it work if you run/build the app from the command line outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: @EgorKlepikov i try but it gives me same errors...

Comment: Did you click refresh in the IntelliJ Maven tool window? Do you get the same issue when running from command line?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed!

Comment: Keep in mind that the dependencies listed in your pom.xml may be implicitly bringing in additional dependencies. Put another way, your nominal pom is not the same thing as your effective pom, which may be ~10X greater.  
To see it in Intellij, click the Maven tab on the right-hand side of the window, right-click on your project name and select "Show Effective POM".

Comment: @Howard007 how can that help me to fix that?

Comment: "i have no elasticsearch plugins, no elasticsearch dependency and no elasticsearch properties in the application properties"
To be certain of what dependencies you have, check your Effective POM.